# Parenthesise math expression if it contains operator

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

Imagine I have written several fractions of the form `$\frac{V+W}{U}$` and decide later that I want them to be displayed as a slashed fraction instead. In the group where I want this to happen, I can always do `\renewcommand\frac[2]{#1/#2}`. However, I would like to add parenthesis to the numerator (or the denominator) *only if* it contains a `mathop`. At least, this seems to me a suitable first heuristic for deciding whether the numerator (denominator) is to be parenthesised or not.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, I search for `+`,  `-`, `\bullet`, and `\cdot`, but you can add more operators to the `\setsepchar` list.

Also, if the operator is leading, such as `-3`, I do not add parens.  You could change that by commenting the line `\ignoreemptyitems`.

EDITED to workaround a strange error when `\sim` appears by itself as an argument to `\inlinefrac`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\inlinefrac[2]{
  \setsepchar{+||-||\bullet||\cdot||\oplus}
  \ignoreemptyitems
  \readlist*\xator{ #1}
  \ifnum\listlen\xator[]>1\relax(#1)\else{#1}\fi
  /
  \readlist*\xator{ #2}
  \ifnum\listlen\xator[]>1\relax(#2)\else{#2}\fi
}
\begin{document}
\[
  \frac{2}{3}\quad\let\frac\inlinefrac\frac{2}{3}
\]
\[
  \frac{2}{-3}\quad\let\frac\inlinefrac\frac{2}{-3}
\]
\[
  \frac{2+x}{3}\quad\let\frac\inlinefrac\frac{2+x}{3}
\]
\[
  \frac{2\bullet x}{3\cdot y}\quad\inlinefrac{2\bullet x}{3\cdot y}
\]
\centering$\inlinefrac{M\oplus N}{\sim}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very good to me, in particular because it is clear what is happening. However, the document won't compile if it contains e.g. `$\ifrac{M\oplus N}{\sim}$`. Can you see why?

Comment: @Bubaya It appears to be something with the `\sim`.  I'm looking further...

Comment: @Bubaya I have provided an edit to handle this case.  Not sure why the prior code had an issue.

Comment: Indeed this works; do you know why you workaround works by the original solution did not?

Comment: @Bubaya For some reason, the `\readlist{\sim}` provokes an error, while adding a prespace `\readlist{ \sim}` does not.  So, I just used instead `\readlist*` which strips leading and trailing spaces from the list items.  I am conferring with my co-author of `listofitems` to seek out a better understanding.

Comment: @Bubaya My coauthor, Christian Tellechia, informs me that "An infinite loop starts because `\sim` is not a primitive and is not expandable".  A bug fix for the package will be published soon.  Thank you for discovering this bug, so that we may fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I propose an `\ifrac` command. If given with `*` it will call `\inlinefrac`, but it will also obey the setting done by `\fractionsinline` (local setting).

This way it's easy to switch from one form to the other, by adding or removing `*`. You can also use `\inlinefrac` directly.

Symbols that trigger the parentheses need not be the same in the numerator and the denominator: multiplication symbols should trigger parentheses in the denominator only.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\ifrac}{smm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   { \inlinefrac { #2 } { #3 } }
   {
    \bool_if:NTF \l_bubaya_frac_inline_bool
     {
      \inlinefrac { #2 } { #3 }
     }
     {
      \frac { #2 } { #3 }
     }
   }
 }

\bool_new:N \l_bubaya_frac_inline_bool

% extend the regex at will; \+ and \- stand for + and -,
% \c{command name} for a control sequence
\regex_const:Nn \c_bubaya_frac_num_regex { \+ | \- | \c{sin} | \c{cos} }
\regex_const:Nn \c_bubaya_frac_den_regex { \c{cdot} | \c{times} | \c{bullet} }

\NewDocumentCommand{\fractionsinline}{}
 {
  \bool_set_true:N \l_bubaya_frac_inline_bool
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\inlinefrac}{mm}
 {
  \regex_match:NnTF \c_bubaya_frac_num_regex { #1 } { (#1) } { #1 }
  /
  \regex_match:NnTF \c_bubaya_frac_num_regex { #2 }
   {
    (#2)
   }
   {
    \regex_match:NnTF \c_bubaya_frac_den_regex { #2 } { (#2) } { #2 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \ifrac{2}{3}\qquad\ifrac*{2}{3}
\\
  \ifrac{2}{-3}\qquad\ifrac*{2}{-3}
\\
  \fractionsinline
  \ifrac{2}{-3}\qquad\ifrac{2}{-3}
\\
  \inlinefrac{2+x}{3}
\\
  \ifrac{\sin x}{x}\qquad\ifrac*{\sin x}{x}
\\
\end{gather*}

\fractionsinline
\begin{gather*}
  \ifrac{2+x}{3}
\\
  \ifrac{2\bullet x}{3\cdot y}
\\
  \ifrac{\sin x}{x}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1)... Commenting to tell you that you made the same mistake with me: In a first "math thought" you don't really need parentheses for multiplication, but only for addition/transaction. In a second thought... it is really needed because : "\ifrac{2\bullet x}{3\cdot y}" can be read only like: "2\bullet x / (3\cdot y)" or "2\bullet x/ 3/ y" and in no case like 2\bullet x/ 3\cdot y....

Comment: @koleygr I leave the choice to add what's needed to the OP. I'd simply type my fractions with the slash or in `\frac` notation, without resorting to automatic (and fallible) methods.

Comment: Right, but I still think that the denominator needs its own checks and has to be in parentheses in more cases than the numerator has... And this makes the question somehow more difficult in order of real checks needed for an automated accepted result.

Comment: @koleygr Agreed and edited accordingly.

Comment: The other thing that would improve the code is that `\sin` and `\cos` and whatever function, doesn't really need parenthesis if it is followed by one and only one variable. For me... `\sin3x` is a wrong way to write `\sin(3x)` because it is not really clear but `\sin Whatever`, when "Whatever" is clearly a single variable is always clear and the only clear thing. This is for functions like log too but is a case that my teachers always disagreed with me and I always feel that my opinion would lead to more clear math phrases. Even `\sin 2\pi` seems wrong to me... Perfect answer!

Comment: @koleygr That's a different cup of tea and unrelated to the problem at hand. In my opinion `\sin3x` doesn't need parentheses, but that's just opinion: multiplication by an explicit number binds more than other multiplications, so there is no danger of confusion.

Comment: You are right that this is a different thing... Stopping the discussion just because it is not really related to this question/answer and possibly not to TeX.SX too... (But my opinion is that it would make things easier in reading from non advanced "math users" and for me this can only be an advantage)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with the same idea as @Steven's solution but by using `xstring` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\renewcommand\frac[2]{\IfSubStr{#1}{+}{(#1)}{\IfSubStr{#1}{-}{(#1)}{#1}}/\IfSubStr{#2}{+}{(#2)}{\IfSubStr{#2}{-}{(#2)}{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\(\frac{5}{10}=0.5\) but \(\frac{5+1}{10}=0.6\) and \(\frac{7}{10+4}=0.5\) but \(\frac{14+1}{6+1.5}=2\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: I suggest Steven's solution as easier to expanded for more cases, but had already created this code before see his answer and thus, posted.